# Should my two part question be asked separately?

Tags: discussion, questions, too-broad

I've asked a [question about error analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303130) and included a follow up question which is strongly related to the first one. I'm unsure whether it would be best to post them as separate questions.

I'm new to this stack, and I worry that if I post them both, I might seem like I'm spamming, but on the other hand, my initial question is already pretty long, and so it might seem like I'm asking too much for 1 question.

Last thing, I didn't include the actual real-world problem that inspired this question because I felt the the question was long enough as it is, and I figured the general case would make a better, more interesting question than my specific problem.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your question? I certainly don't think asking 2 questions is too much / spamming in general.

Comment: @gung done, thought I had.  I suppose I'm just not sure whether it's better to separate them out as there is some overlap

Comment: If the second one is a follow-up I would include in it a link to the first. If people who answer need more context first they will ask for it, or in the worst case vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @mdewey my issue is I don't know if the second part of that question warrants being split off into a separate question or not, or if it should be kept with the original question.